# intel graphics stuck

Tags: graphics, intel

Crossposted from: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469605/intel-graphics-screen-stuck?noredirect=1#comment2576180_1469605

I have a laptop with intel integrated graphics and an nvidia graphics card. From time to time, if there is a sudden change to the screen, the screen will get stuck in the previous state. It will stay in this state until i change the screen again, e.g I move down a page in a pdf, the screen stays in the state before the movement and will only fully turn the page if i jiggle the page up and down again.

I blacklisted the nouveau driver in /etc/modprobe.d/ and sudo lshw -c video shows that the nvidia card does not have a driver currently so i assume it is not being used but the problem still persists, so i do not think the nvidia driver is responsible. Any help would be appreciated.